# Facebook cannot crawl Heroku App (No Such App)

Tags: facebook, heroku

I have an app in Heroku that serves static files, my problem is that when the site is shared in Facebook and tested with Facebook debugger it says no such app. Looking at my application log I can see that the `host` being passed is facebook crawler host which certainly Heroku would not recognize.

For example I have a domain like this

`CNAME www > points to > myapp.heroku.com`

Now access through `www` and `myapp.heroku.com` works fine. The problem is when I test the `www` domain and even the Heroku app link with Facebook debugger it says `Heroku | No Such App`

Is there a way to circumvent this issue?